# Airflow and Ray runtime: Out of memory issue

Tags: docker, docker-compose, multiprocessing, airflow, ray

I'm currently facing a Ray/Airflow issue and I need your help. I use Airflow via a Docker compose script which includes my containerized app and its modules. Some of the modules are exposed via APIs for AI inference (modules A) while others are used for processing data and training an AI model (modules B). I trigger the modules B via Airflow DAGs tasks to automate the workflows and data validations. These modules use the Ray library to accelerate data collection/processing and the model training.

Using a `BashOperator` task - i.e. executing a python script in my app container via a Docker command from the Airflow DAG (Docker in Docker situation) - I run the modules B successfully. However, I quickly reach an `out of memory (OOM)` issue with many Ray workers being killed constantly (from 10 to 30). I have for now specified the number of Ray workers to be maximum 4, and set the Airflow environment parameters related to parallelism and workers to minimum (see below) in the Docker compose file. But this setup doesn't solve the problem. Is there any way to make Ray and Airflow work correctly?

```
AIRFLOW__CORE__PARALLELISM: 1  # max task instances a scheduler can execute concurrently
AIRFLOW__CORE__DAG_CONCURRENCY: 1  # max task instances allowed to run concurrently within a single DAG
AIRFLOW__CORE__MAX_ACTIVE_RUNS_PER_DAG: 1  # max active DAG runs for a single DAG
AIRFLOW__CORE__WORKERS: 1  # number of worker processes to launch (for all tasks)
AIRFLOW__CORE__WORKER_CONCURRENCY: 1  # max tasks a worker can execute concurrently
AIRFLOW__CORE__MAX_THREADS: 1  # max threads a single Airflow process (scheduler or web server) can use
AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTE_TASKS_NEW_PYTHON_INTERPRETER: 'true'
```

Comment: What's your docker compose configuration for the ray container? What's your limits on the docker engine itself?

Comment: I start Ray in parallel to the app (within the same container). The command `ray start --head --port 6379 --num-cpus=4` is triggered before the app launches. Regarding the Docker container, there's no memory limit imposed so it has access to my host machine's memory (16 GB).